# Why is the hash removed from the URL when you're at the root path?

Tags: url, browser, hyperlink, routes

In the URL, when I want to visit root_path/#hash it removes the "#". Does anyone know why?

For example, if you go to somesite.com/#some_hash, the url gets changed to somesite.com/some_hash, and then when you try to reload the page, it tries to visit the /some_hash path.

I've noticed this only happens with the root path. For example, if you go to somesite.com/somepath/#some_hash, it does not have the same problem. The "#" is preserved.

Why does this happen and is there any way to prevent it from happening? This creates problems when trying to create links to sections on the same page.

Comment: https://www.google.com/# The hash stays. This is unrelated to whether the fragment is used at the root or not. I guess that it might be some specific implementation of the website you were looking at.

Comment: It will not happen to all sites. You can try http://stackoverflow.com/#helloworld  It does not remove hash URL. This might happen if the site is single page application and try to use HTML5 history for clean URL.